# Plotting conjugate diameters of an ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

Good morning, I'm drawing an ellipse with its conjugate deameters. My MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0:360,no markers]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}{
      \addplot ({x/360},{#1+x/360});
      \addplot ({#1+x/360},{#1-1.07*x/360});
      \addplot ({5*sin(x)},{4*cos(x)});
         }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Questions - how to make straight lines longer enough? How to make an ellipse smoother? Thanks!

Comment: for smoother draw of ellipse ad `smooth` option to `tikzpicture`  or to `addplot`. Regarding lines, I don't understand  what you meaning with  "longer". Where they should be (from where to where)?

Comment: They should fill an ellipse. Every line has its ends on elipse

Comment: Than you have mathematical problem :-) Coordinates for lines are wrong calculated. They should be on  ellipse border.  Another solution is use intersection library .... see description in the section "13.3.2 Intersections of Arbitrary Paths" on page 136 of recent TikZ manual. There are some examples how to do this.

Comment: Give me the link on recent Tikz manual please

Comment: Here it is: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf (look at section 13.3.2)

Comment: @OlgaK, sorry, temporary I haven't time to give you more help. Maybe late evening (GMT), if someone wouldn't meantime help you. I suppose, that you have last TikZ installed. Manual is part of it installation and at MikTeX is in directory `.../Program Files/MikTeX 2.9/doc/genereic/pgf/pgfmanula.pdf` . Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thnk you, no problem. I am learning more tikz manual

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what `conjugate diameters` are, but with an `ellipse` shaped node and its polar anchors, it's easy to draw lines between any two points on ellipse border.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[ellipse, draw, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm] (A) {};

\draw (A.30)--(A.210);
\draw (A.40)--(A.200);
\draw (A.120)--(A.300);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: my congradulations, now you know about conj diamaters)) And I know about anchors. Probably, your treat is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, due to all recommendations above I arrived to folowing

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[help lines/.style={blue!30,very thin},scale=0.6]
\draw [help lines] (-6, -3) grid (6, 3);
\draw[->] (-6, 0) -- (6, 0) node[below]{\footnotesize $x$};
\draw[->] (0, -3) -- (0, 3) node[right]{\footnotesize $y$};
\draw[color=blue,very thick] (0, 0) ellipse (4cm and 2cm);

\draw[-,green!50!black] (2, -2) -- (5, 1) ; 
\draw[-,green!50!black] (1, -2) -- (4, 1) ;
\draw[-,green!50!black] (0, -2) -- (4, 2);
\draw[-,green!50!black] (-1, -2) -- (3, 2);
\draw[-,green!50!black] (-2, -2) -- (2, 2);

\draw[-,green!50!black] (-5, -1) -- (-2, 2) ;
\draw[-,green!50!black] (-4, -1) -- (-1, 2) ;
\draw[-,green!50!black] (-4, -2) -- (0, 2) ;
\draw[-,green!50!black] (-3, -2) -- (1, 2) ;

\draw[-,red] (-4, 1) -- (4, -1) ;
\draw[-,red] (-3, 2) -- (5, 0) ;
\draw[-,red] (-5, 0) -- (3, -2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: conjugate diameters]